# Magento 2.2.3 How to change GrandTotal

Tags: checkout, customer, quote, shipping-address, billing-address

```
            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
            var billingCountryId = (billingAddress.countryId);
            // console.log(billingCountryId);
            console.log({billing: billingCountryId});


            if (billingCountryId == shippingCountryId) {
                alert("shipping and billing matches");
            }
            else {
                alert("shipping and billing different error");
            }

            shippingRates(ratesData);
            shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);
```

I want to add the tax rate back in on GrandTotal if the country is different for shipping and billing. is this possible through the same JS file

Comment: mention your Magento version.